# Gridview controllers null after inserting column

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am developing a Web App for managing Student exam entries but I am coming across an issue with my gridview.

The basic idea is that a user can go on and enter and update details on a students exam. Complications arise when certain subjects require different fields to be populated and this is where my issue is.

The exception is thrown when the Save Button method is run. I get a Null Object reference thrown when running the AddAudit and UpdateRecord methods. After some debugging from the looks of it the issue is the controls (ddlDate, txtAssesmentLevel etc) are not being declared from the FindCotrol method of the gridview meaning when the AddAudit and UpdateRecord methods are called they point to a null controller.

Be aware that this issue does not occur when the code is not "C2555" which leads me to suspect the issue is with dynamically adding columns and controls getting muddled up though i am not sure.

Any assistance would be great and feel free to ask for more information.

Below is my basic code:

Page Load Method

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){

if(!IsPostBack){
//Selected class passed through
  selectedClass sc = (selectedClass)Session["selectedClass"] as selectedClass;

//Get Class Code
  lblAosCode.Text = sc.getAOSCode();

//If class is English
  if(lblAosCode.Text == "C2555"){
    TemplateField speakingListening = new TemplateField();
    speakingListening.HeaderText = "Speaking and Listening";
    dgvSelectedClasses.Columns.Insert(7, speakingListening);   
  }


//Populate Gridview
 DataTable dsSelectedClasses = AccessData.getSelectedClasses(sc.getAOSCode(), sc.getAOSPeriod(), sc.getDescription());    
 dgvSelectedClasses.DataSource = dsSelectedClasses;
 dgvSelectedClasses.DataBind();



//Check if txtAssesmentLevel is populated
 for (int index = 0; index < dgvSelectedClasses.Rows.Count; index++)
            {
             TextBox txtAssessmentLevel = (TextBox)dgvSelectedClasses.Rows[index].FindControl("txtAssessmentLevel");
                if (dgvBefore.Rows[index].Cells[4].Text != " ")
                {
                    txtAssessmentLevel.ReadOnly = true;
                }
            }
 }


}
```

Save Method (Exception Thrown)

```
protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {



        for (int i = 0; i < dgvSelectedClasses.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            DropDownList ddlL1L2 = (DropDownList)dgvSelectedClasses.Rows[i].FindControl("ddlL1L2");
            DropDownList ddlExamDate = (DropDownList)dgvSelectedClasses.Rows[i].FindControl("ddlExamDate");
            TextBox txtAssessmentLevel = (TextBox)dgvSelectedClasses.Rows[i].FindControl("txtAssessmentLevel");
            DropDownList ddlSpeakingListening = null;
            if (lblAosCode.Text.Contains("C2555"))
            {
                ddlSpeakingListening = (DropDownList)dgvSelectedClasses.Rows[i].FindControl("ddlSpeakingListening");
            }




            if (IsPostBack)
            {
                if (lblAosCode.Text.Contains("C2555"))
                {
                    AccessData.addAudit(dgvSelectedClasses.Rows[i].Cells[0].Text, Context.User.Identity.Name, "Assessment Level", txtAssessmentLevel.Text, dgvBefore.Rows[i].Cells[4].Text);
                    AccessData.addAudit(dgvSelectedClasses.Rows[i].Cells[0].Text, Context.User.Identity.Name, "Exam request L1 or L2", ddlL1L2.SelectedValue, dgvBefore.Rows[i].Cells[14].Text);
                    AccessData.addAudit(dgvSelectedClasses.Rows[i].Cells[0].Text, Context.User.Identity.Name, "Exam Date", ddlExamDate.SelectedValue, dgvBefore.Rows[i].Cells[15].Text);
                    AccessData.addAudit(dgvSelectedClasses.Rows[i].Cells[0].Text, Context.User.Identity.Name, "Speaking and Listening", ddlSpeakingListening.SelectedValue, dgvBefore.Rows[i].Cells[7].Text);

                    AccessData.updateRecord(txtAssessmentLevel.Text, ddlL1L2.SelectedValue, ddlExamDate.SelectedValue, lblAosCode.Text, lblAosPeriod.Text, dgvSelectedClasses.Rows[i].Cells[0].Text, ddlSpeakingListening.SelectedValue);
                }
                else
                {
                    AccessData.addAudit(dgvSelectedClasses.Rows[i].Cells[0].Text, Context.User.Identity.Name, "Assessment Level", txtAssessmentLevel.Text, dgvBefore.Rows[i].Cells[4].Text);
                    AccessData.addAudit(dgvSelectedClasses.Rows[i].Cells[0].Text, Context.User.Identity.Name, "Exam request L1 or L2", ddlL1L2.SelectedValue, dgvBefore.Rows[i].Cells[13].Text);
                    AccessData.addAudit(dgvSelectedClasses.Rows[i].Cells[0].Text, Context.User.Identity.Name, "Exam Date", ddlExamDate.SelectedValue, dgvBefore.Rows[i].Cells[14].Text);

                    AccessData.updateRecord(txtAssessmentLevel.Text, ddlL1L2.SelectedValue, ddlExamDate.SelectedValue, lblAosCode.Text, lblAosPeriod.Text, dgvSelectedClasses.Rows[i].Cells[0].Text);
                }
            }

        }

        Response.Redirect("~/contact");


    }
```

On Row Data Bound

```
protected void OnRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {

            if (lblAosCode.Text.Contains("C2555"))
            {
                DropDownList ddlSpeakingListening = new DropDownList();
                ddlSpeakingListening.ID = "ddlSpeakingListening";
                ddlSpeakingListening.Items.Add("L1");
                ddlSpeakingListening.Items.Add("L2");
                ddlSpeakingListening.Items.Add("Entry");
                ddlSpeakingListening.Items.Add("NS");
                e.Row.Cells[7].Controls.Add(ddlSpeakingListening);




            }

        }
    }
```

ASP.NET

```
<asp:GridView ID="dgvSelectedClasses" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnRowDataBound="OnRowDataBound">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="StudentID" HeaderText="Student ID" ReadOnly="True" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="StageCode" HeaderText="Stage Code" ReadOnly="True" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Forename" HeaderText="Forename" ReadOnly="True" />
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Surname" DataField="Surname" />
                <asp:TemplateField  HeaderText="Assessment Level">

                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtAssessmentLevel" Text ='<%#Bind("AssessmetLevel") %>' runat="server" Width="50px"></asp:TextBox>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="TargetLevel" HeaderText="Target Level" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Achievelevel" HeaderText="Achieve Level" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="FELSOutcome" HeaderText="FELS Outcome" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Registration" HeaderText="Registration" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="DateSpreadsheetSent" HeaderText="Last Update" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Dayofclass" HeaderText="Day of class" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Timeofclass" HeaderText="Time of class" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Location" HeaderText="Location" />
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Exam request L1 or L2" >
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlL1L2" runat="server" >
                            <asp:ListItem>Not Set</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>L1</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>L2</asp:ListItem>

                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Exam date">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlExamDate" runat="server">

                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>


<asp:GridView ID="dgvBefore" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="StudentID" HeaderText="Student ID" ReadOnly="True" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="StageCode" HeaderText="Stage Code" ReadOnly="True" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Forename" HeaderText="Forename" ReadOnly="True" />
            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Surname" DataField="Surname" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="AssessmetLevel" HeaderText="Assessment Level" NullDisplayText=" "/>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="TargetLevel" HeaderText="Target Level" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="AchieveLevel" HeaderText="Achieve Level" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="FELSOutcome" HeaderText="FELS Outcome" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Registration" HeaderText="Registration" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="DateSpreadsheetSent" HeaderText="Date Spreadsheet Sent" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Dayofclass" HeaderText="Day of class" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Timeofclass" HeaderText="Time of class" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Location" HeaderText="Location" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ExamrequestL1orL2" HeaderText="Exam request L1 or L2" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Examdate" HeaderText="Exam date" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Reviewed" HeaderText="Reviewed" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

P.S. This is my first question hopefully it makes sense and I am open to pointers :)

Edit: The page load method does include code to populate dgvBefore as well as a few authentications thing i just forgot to include it.

Comment: James, the question is not clear though you have pasted a lot of code. Could you please update it with exact problem statement?

Comment: @A3006 The problem is when i press the save button there is a null object reference exception thrown. The Controls from the gridview are not being assigned where I use the Find Control Method at the start of the Save Method. The error only occurs when the new "ddlSpeakingListening" column is added.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add the drop down list column on every postback. Refer this link : https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/682689/Add-populated-dropdownlist-to-GridView-dynamically